# R: Unicode in png output for xyplot

Tags: r, unicode, plot, png, cairo

**I wish to include a unicode character in the PNG output of xyplot** on Windows 7 with R 3.0.1. E.g. (note the **µ** in the expression in ylab)

```
## output to windows() works fine
xyplot(CD4 ~ obstime, groups=aids$patient, data=aids, type="b", ylab=expression(sqrt("CD4/µl")))

## output to PNG does not
png(file="AIDS.png", width=5, height=5, units="in", type="cairo", res=800)
xyplot(CD4 ~ obstime, groups=aids$patient, data=aids, type="b", ylab=expression(sqrt("CD4/µl")))
dev.off()
```

I get the error "Metric information not available for this device".

I think this might be a general issue with unicode and png(), as using plot(1, main="µ") prints µ for windows() output, but not for png() output (where the µ is silently omitted). However, using CairoPNG does not resolve this issue: it prints µ for plot(), but the error with xyplot() remains (xyplot also seems to ignore the pointsize= for Cairo).

Comment: I don't see any "Unicode" characters being specified. Just ordinary plotmath. The production of that plot takes a long time on my Mac with the default png() device even with minimal data.

Comment: There is a Unicode µ in the ylab.
Regarding computation time: you can subset the aids dataset, e.g. replace aids with aids[1:50,] and aids$patient with aids$patient[1:50][drop=T]. You can further speed up PNG creation by changing res=800 to a lower value, e.g. res=100. A plot with minimal data should suffice to reproduce the problem with the axis labels, I have used the full dataset here for simplicity. The res parameter might be important for any solutions using Cairo, as there is a need to scale up the fonts for higher resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (using plotmath expression interpretation):

```
png(file="AIDS.png", width=5, height=5, units="in", type="cairo", res=800)
xyplot(1 ~ 1,  type="b", ylab=expression(sqrt(CD4/µ*l)))
dev.off()
```

Or:

```
png(file="AIDS.png", width=5, height=5, units="in", type="cairo", res=800)
xyplot(1 ~ 1,  type="b", ylab=expression(sqrt(CD4/mu*l)))
dev.off()
```

(Either of these was much faster on my device than getting png() to do whatever it did with the character version.)

Comment: Thank you, the second solution worked for me (the first did not for some reason).

Comment: The first one depended on having your graphics font in common. The second was using the Symbol font, which all R installations are supposed to share. See ?plotmath Details section.